# Como quitar el Randomize

Tags: visual-studio, excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office

he descargado este material de youtube un juego denominado el ahorcado , el problema es que como las palabras son aleatorias se repiten muy seguido,megustaria que me ayudaran a buscar la forma de cambiar esa opción y que simplemente tomo las palabras en el orden en que se encuentran.

Este es el video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ7NtIClH8A

```
Public Palabrita() As String  'Arreglo para cada letra
Public Longitud As Integer
Public Abecedario(1 To 27) As String
Public RestoLetras() As String
Sub JuegoAhorcado()
    Dim UltFilaD As Integer
    Dim Palabra As String
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim Lista As String
        
    'Asigna el abecedario al vector Abecedario()
    For K = 1 To 27
        Abecedario(K) = Sheets("Diccionario").Cells(1, 7 + K)
    Next K
    
    'Se selecciona la palabra a adivinar aleatoriamente de la lista
    Randomize
    UltFilaD = Sheets("Diccionario").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Num = Int((UltFilaD + 2 - 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Palabra = UCase(Sheets("Diccionario").Cells(Num, 3))
    
    'Cantidad de letras de la palabra a adivinar y se redimension el vector Palabrita()
    Longitud = Len(Palabra)
    Sheets("Jugar").Cells(4, 7) = Longitud
    ReDim Palabrita(1 To Longitud)
    
    'Se asigna la palabra al vector Palabrita()
    For J = 1 To Longitud
        Palabrita(J) = Mid(Palabra, J, 1)
    Next J
    
    ' Se asigna borde a tantas celdas como letra tenga la palabra
    For I = 3 To 2 + Longitud
        Sheets("Jugar").Cells(6, I).BorderAround (xlDouble)
        Sheets("Jugar").Cells(6, I).Interior.Color = 10086143
    Next I
    
    'Se genera un vector Restoletras() con las letras del abecedario que no hacen parte de la palabra a adivinar
    ReDim RestoLetras(1 To 27)
    RestoLetras() = Abecedario()
    
    For J = 1 To Longitud
        For M = 1 To 27
            If Palabrita(J) = RestoLetras(M) Then
                RestoLetras(M) = ""
            End If
        Next M
    Next J
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yo lo que haría, sería añadir otro diccionario que almacene las palabras ya jugadas para evitar que vuelvan a salir (dentro de la misma partida).

Comment: Como se hace, no la mas remota idea